# Why isn't my map full?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I'm on sequence 6. I have visited all the high spots in Boston and the Frontier, but the maps still have patches of unknown territory that I need to discover by foot. The stats screen says that I've reached 73% of all the high points, I assume that the remaining 27% are in NY.

How do I complete the maps for the cities and frontier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even using the high points, some parts of the map are still greyed out.  However, you can run there to make them appear.  In addition, the peddlars sell maps that show the hidden items (chests, feathers, etc.) even if they are in the grey areas, so you don't really need to go *everywhere*.  Just buy the maps and chase *them* down.

Comment: Think about it this way - these aren't very dense locations, it's hard to get a vantage point to see everything.  You're not in Rome anymore!

Comment: Also, forts seem to remain undetectable by synchronizing. Just a sidenote.